# codeigniter active record querying for results based on hours as well as by state

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have two queries ultimately I think they will be in the same context of the other but in all. I have a user database that I want to pull out for tracking records based on hour. Example registrations per hour. But in this registrations per hour I want to have the query to dump results by hour increments (or weeks, or months) ie: 1,000 regitrations in november, 1,014 in december and so on, or similar for weeks hours.

I also have a similar query where I want to generate a list of states with the counts next to them of how many users I have per state.

My issue is, I'm thinking I think to one dimensionally currently cause the best idea I can think of at the moment is making in the case of the states 50 queries, but I know thats insane, and there has to be an easier way thats less intense. So thats what Im hoping someone from here can help me with, by giving me a general idea. Cause I don't know which is the best course of action for this currently.. be it using `distinct`, `group_by` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment a bit and see if that doesn't help you focus on the question a bit more.

Try selecting from your registrations per hour table and appending the time buckets you are interested in to the select list.

like this:

```
select userid, regid, date_time, week(date_time), year(date_time), day(date_time)
from registraions;
```

you can then roll up and count things in that table by using group by and an aggregate function like this:

```
select count(distinct userid), year(date_time)
from registraions
group by year(date_time)
```

Read about about date time functions:
[MySQL Date Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Read about aggregate functions"
[MySQL Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)